# How to put single quotes insode of variable's value in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a problem and i cannot find a solution.

I am writing a shell script and I need to be able to send this information:

```
/usr/bin/wget --header='Content-Type: application/xml'
```

currently I have this in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
HEADER="Content-Type: application/xml"
PARAM_HEADER="--header=\'$HEADER\'"
/usr/bin/wget $PARAM_HEADER
```

But when I run the script I see I run the command as this:

```
/usr/bin/wget '--header=\'\''Content-Type:' 'application/xml\'\'''
```

please help!!

Comment: FYI, all-uppercase is conventional for environment variables and builtins, not regular shell variables. Using lowercase for regular variables is preferable, because that way you can't overwrite an environment variable by mistake (or, worse, a builtin -- several of which lose their special behavior if assigned to).

Comment: Hi thanks for your info. And yes, it make sense to keep shell variables not in uppercase, thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to be able to safely preserve argument boundaries:

```
#!/bin/bash
header="Content-Type: application/xml"

params=( )                       # initialize to empty array
params+=( "--header=$header" )   # add your argument
params+=( '--header=X-Foo: something with spaces' ) # add another

/usr/bin/wget "${params[@]}"
```

Note that single-vs-double-quotes only matters to the shell -- when `wget` is run, it gets passed an array of C strings, and has no idea of what kind of quotes were used to protect any of those strings at the shell (or, for that matter, whether it was started using a shell at all). The *representation* of those strings given by `set -x` is just that -- a representation in shell syntax.

See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for details on the source of the problem and alternate approaches.